# No Content in Spring Boot Rest

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http-status-code-204

How do I configure Spring Boot to return 204 in GET methods (typically findAll methods) when the method does not fetch records? I would not like to do treatment in each method, type the code below:

```
if(!result)
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK)
```

I'd like to transform this method:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> findAll(){
    List<User> result = service.findAll();
    return !result.isEmpty() ? 
            new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK) : new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

In this one:

```
@GetMapping
public List<User> findAll(){
    return service.findAll();
}
```

If the result from **findAll()** is empty or null then my controller should return **204** instead of **200**.

Answer (score 7):

You could register a custom [`ResponseBodyAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html) which allows customizing the response of `@ResponseBody` or `ResponseEntity` handler methods (right before the content is being serialized by a `MessageConverter`):

```
@ControllerAdvice
class NoContentControllerAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<List<?>> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return List.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public List<?> beforeBodyWrite(List<?> body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
               Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
               ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {

        if (body.isEmpty()) {
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return body;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this pays no attention to the current value of the response. This is a good solution when modifying a 200 OK with null body to a 204, but this would also do the same thing for a 500 or 400? Would exception handlers bypass this?

Comment: @Dennis well it tests the actual response body (the java.util.List). And if an exception occurs inside a handler-method (before a response is returned) - this advice is not fired.

Comment: So I guess the strategy is to fire an exception for non 200 cases and then let this handler assume that all it will do is switch 200 -> 204 in some scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: @fateddy will return []  Incase of Array/List return type  ?